# Swift: Search bar created at Auto Focus

Tags: swift, search, uisearchcontroller, autofocus

I am creating a table view and a search bar by clicking on a button.But I need the search bar to appear at Auto Focus ( where the user enters text immediately with no need to click inside the search bar). How can I do that ?

Answer (score 17):

try this

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: Old answer but still worked for me in SwiftUI.

Comment: 2021-07-02, still working in SwiftUI for iOS 14!

Answer (score 3):

This should do it.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    searchController.active = true
}
```

...

```
extension GDSearchTableViewController: UISearchControllerDelegate {
   func didPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
      searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
   }
}
```

Comment: When using a UISearchController, this is the only thing that worked for me

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5.2**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    searchController.isActive = true
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchController.delegate = self
}

extension ViewController: UISearchControllerDelegate {
    func didPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
        searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```